# ruby hashes, why is the value getting overridden

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

Consider the following code snippet:

```
inner_hash =Hash.new
 trial_hash = Hash.new
inner_hash.merge!("i_key1"=>"value1")
inner_hash.merge!("i_key2"=>"value2")
puts "inner_hash #{inner_hash}"
trial_hash.merge!("o_key1"=>inner_hash)
puts "trial_hash #{trial_hash}"
inner_hash.clear
inner_hash.merge!("i_key1"=>"value3")
inner_hash.merge!("i_key2"=>"value4")
puts "inner_hash #{inner_hash}"
trial_hash.merge!("o_key2"=>inner_hash)
puts "trial_hash #{trial_hash}"
```

This is what it prints:

```
inner_hash {"i_key1"=>"value1", "i_key2"=>"value2"}
trial_hash {"o_key1"=>{"i_key1"=>"value1", "i_key2"=>"value2"}}
inner_hash {"i_key1"=>"value3", "i_key2"=>"value4"}
trial_hash {"o_key1"=>{"i_key1"=>"value3", "i_key2"=>"value4"}, "o_key2"=>{"i_key1"=>"value3", "i_key2"=>"value4"}}
```

Especially see the trial_hash printed in the last line. The value of key "o_key1" is a hash whose value should have been value1 and value2 but have been overwritten to value3 and value4. ideally the expected output should have been:

```
inner_hash {"i_key1"=>"value1", "i_key2"=>"value2"}
trial_hash {"o_key1"=>{"i_key1"=>"value1", "i_key2"=>"value2"}}
inner_hash {"i_key1"=>"value3", "i_key2"=>"value4"}
trial_hash {"o_key1"=>{"i_key1"=>"value1", "i_key2"=>"value2"}, "o_key2"=>{"i_key1"=>"value3", "i_key2"=>"value4"}}
```

Why is this behaviour observed. What wrong am I doing. Originally the question is very broad and uses loops, which for sample purpose here, i have removed and re-written some of the lines. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**: The problem is solved when I replaced inner_hash.clear with inner_hash={}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
trial_hash.merge!("o_key1"=>inner_hash)
```

a **reference** of `inner_hash` is made as the value. So whenever `inner_hash` changes, `trial_hash["o_key1"]` changes accordingly, because they are references to the same `Hash` object.

Check out their `object_id`, the same:

```
trial_hash["o_key1"].object_id
#=> 21676080
trial_hash["o_key2"].object_id
#=> 21676080
inner_hash.object_id
#=> 21676080
```

---

You could get your expected behavior if using `clone`:

```
trial_hash.merge!("o_key1"=>inner_hash.clone)
```

Comment: got it, what is the alternative then?

Comment: To my surprise, this does not happen when I changed the code from inner_hash.clear to inner_hash={}

Comment: @Inquisitive `inner_hash={} ` would make `inner_hash` a reference to a new `Hash` object.

Comment: got it, what is the better approach, using inner_hash ={} or inner_hash.clone?

Comment: @Inquisitive What's important is to understand what's going on exactly. There are other methods that modifies a `Hash` other than `Hash#clear`. For instance, if you insert into `inner_hash` a new key/value, `trial_hash["o_key1"]` would change accordingly if it references to the same `Hash`.